# Http caching in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I try to use standart AppCache in Symfony2 to make a gateway caching.
The question is the each of theese three ways define when the proxy need to run server script because cache invalid for some reason, and I can use only single of them ?

```
$response->setETag($article->computeETag()); // 1
$response->setLastModified($article->getPublishedAt()); //2
$response->setMaxAge(600); //3
```

I read the doc, but for now it little confused me. Thnaks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Read the docs first. There are two kinds of caching you can use - expiration and validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max age requires last modified.

The ETag is independent of the other two and is a unique identifiert of your page data, so the browser/proxy has a way to check if your content has changed. So it only loads the data from the server if there is a different ETag